# OLEDB External table is not in the expected format / file in different format than extension

Tags: c#, excel, oledb

I am having a weird issue, I am retrieving an excel file (.xls) from a website then exposing the data as JSON, all is working file with dummy document until I started testing with real data, if I download the file and run my code before opening it in excel I get : "External table is not in the expected format.", when I open the file in excel excel gives me a warning that "the file is in a different format than specified by the extension" however if I save it with excel (2010) and select the option for keeping the same format and extension it works right after. the workaround I was thinking about is to automate excel to open and save the file after each download cycle, however I would love to find a real solution instead. [image: Excel] 
Code  : `var pathToExcel = @"\source\repos\Rica2.0\reports\DataExport.xls";
            var sheetName = "Export";
            var connectionString = string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;IMEX=1\";", pathToExcel);`

Comment: The lack of paragraphs and correct use of capital letters makes this question quite hard to read.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that web devs create an html file with a table and give it an xls extension rather than an html extension. They know that users file extensions associates will cause it to be open in Excel and Excel can parse html just fine. And other than that annoying message, it works.

One option is change the file extension to `html` after you download it. Excel will still open an html file and you'll avoid the message. And since you're doing this all programatically, you don't need the shell to work out what program to open via file associations.

Comment: Thank you very much, I was doing the same, changing the extension to xslb solved it for me, but is there another way to parse the file directly in C# without renaming it ? as that would involve creating a directory watcher for tons of different directories to check up for new downloads

Comment: Yes. It's just an html file (text) so you can parse it like you would any other html file. I'm sure c# has a library where you can find the table tag, loop through the tr tags, and loop through the td tags. It's the XML library in VBA, but I don't know what it is in C#.

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking the time to clarify this, I will give it a try

Comment: I figured out how the source file is created, I am positive using this guide http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/creating-a-dynamic-excel-using-html/ 
However I am still not able to parse it or convert it to JSON, now I am running an interloop to this script https://flamingkeys.com/convert-excel-sheet-json-powershell/ but it's not an Ideal solution